# Not able to delete a field using findAndModify query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update existing mongodb document using `findAndModify` query in node.js. I want to add `product_category_ids` field & remove `error_state` field. I want to do these two updates in single query. If I specify only `$set` it is working fine but if I specify both $set & $unset, it sets `product_category_ids` to null value.

my query is as follows:

```
conn.collection('error_import').findAndModify({_id:o_id},[['_id',1]],{ $set: {"product_category_ids":sss.category}}{ $unset: {"error_state":""}},{new:true},function(err,result) {
      if ( err ) 
        console.warn(err);
      else {
        conn.collection('product_import').insert({"tags":result.value.tags, "category_hierarchy":result.value.category_hierarchy, "error_state":result.value.error_state});
      }
});
```

Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
{ $set: {"product_category_ids":sss.category}, $unset: {"error_state":""}}
```

instead of

```
{ $set: {"product_category_ids":sss.category}}{ $unset: {"error_state":""}}
```

Comment: Thanks @shaishab. I tried the solution but it sets error_state field to null instead of removing the field.

Comment: Sample document from my collection:                                                         {
    "_id" : ObjectId("570206bb02664c1400b28702"),                                   
    "error_state" : [ "CATEGORY_IS_MISSING"]
}

Comment: if  `error_state` is an array then `$unset` assign  `null` instead of `remove`  this field. that's `mongodb` valid behavior.  `$unset` remove property if that's not an array. thanks :)

Comment: Could you tell me which operator I should use to remove array field?